# Is my reading/writing in pandas dataframe from differents threads is safe?

Tags: python, multithreading, pandas

My code is quite simple. I have two thread scraping two webpages, filling two dataframes, and then writing two different files.

```
module1.py
df1.to_csv(f1)
df2.to_csv(f2)
```

And I have a different python process who read those two files.

```
module2.py
df3 = pd.read_csv(f1)
df4 = pd.read_csv(f2)
```

Is this thread-safe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you have to worry about thread safety unless the code is running parallelly.